# How can I turn the text from this website into a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want all of the text from this page: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:goog as a variable in the JavaScript on my HTML5 page.

Comment: Have you tried using an XHR? If so, post your attempt here.

Comment: Yes, not sure if I used it properly though... could you give an example?

Comment: There's plenty of examples how to use XHR here, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: Tried XHR... got this in the console XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:goog. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. Menu.html:1

Comment: All the text?  If you said all the text right of the `//` I'd say it looks like a job for `JSON.parse()`...

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's $.get [api.jquery.com/jquery.get/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Read the documentation... Hope it helps.